# selenium でスクレイピングする際 WebDriverException "Can not connect to the Service chromedriver" がおきる

Tags: python, macos, web-scraping

下記のコードをpython3で実行するとエラーが発生します。
seleniumのインストールはpipで行いました。

エラーの「Can not connect to the Service chromedriver」
をどのようにすれば解決するのでしょうか？

ご教授お願いいたします。

[コード]

```
# coding: utf-8

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.jp/')
driver.close()
```

[エラー]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 92, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1):

`Can not connect to the Service chromedriver`というエラーメッセージの下にさらにエラーメッセージが出ていないでしょうか？

MacでPython3.5にseleniumをインストールして実行すると以下のメッセージも出ていました。

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

表示されているURLから自分の環境のファイルをダウンロード。それを回答して`~/bin`などPATHが通っている場所に置いて実行すれば正常に実行できました。

自分の環境ではChromeブラウザはインストール済みですが、こちらも必要だと思います。

ちなみに`Can not connect to the Service chromedriver`というエラーメッセージで[Google検索](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=Can+not+connect+to+the+Service+chromedriver)するだけでも解決方法はたくさん出てきますので、そちらを参照してみるのもよろしいかと。